# Stych OTP with API for expo managed react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm building a react native app and want to use Stych for OTP auth. To do that I need to use their API and send a cURL request which looks something like:

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://test.stytch.com/v1/otps/sms/send \
-u 'MY-SECRET-YO' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "phone_number": "+100000000"
}'
```

See docs [here](https://stytch.com/docs/api/sms-otp-overview).

How do I convert this into a valid request in my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They released a react native SDK that makes this process very easy.